# Lagrange's Remainder for the Taylor formula of $\sin(\cos(t))$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, taylor-expansion

First I am asked to compute the following:

Show that for $0 < x < \frac{\pi}{2}$ we have:

$\sin(x) = x - \frac{x^3}{3!} + R(x)$ and $0 < R(x) < \frac{x^5}{5!}$

This part can be done simply with the Lagrange error bound centered at $x=0$ so this is not an issue. Now in the second part, we are asked to estimate the following integral with an error of $\frac{1}{2\cdot10^3}$.

$$\int_{\frac{\pi}{3}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin(\cos(t))dt$$

My attempt:

I can use what I have shown in the first part of the question and obtain the following:

$$\int_{\frac{\pi}{3}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos(t) -  \frac{\cos(t)^3}{3!}dt + \int_{\frac{\pi}{3}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} R(\cos(t))dt$$

The second part of the integral is our error which has to be less than the given value of $\frac{1}{2\cdot10^3}$. My idea was to rewrite it as follows:

$$\int_{\frac{\pi}{3}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\cos(t)^5}{5!}dt < \int_{\frac{\pi}{3}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{dt}{2^5 \cdot 5!}$$

But I do not think this gets me anywhere. I am aware that if I integrate

$$\int_{\frac{\pi}{3}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\cos(t)^5}{5!}dt$$

I will be within the desired error but I am not sure why. Thanks for any insights!! Also, what if it asked for a way more precise approximation, would I then have to also expand cosine?

Comment: $$\int_{\frac{\pi}{3}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\cos(t)^5}{5!}dt \color{red}<\int_{\frac{\pi}{3}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{dt}{2^5 \cdot 5!}$$

Comment: @AnneBauval Right. So, by this, I know that I have approximated the correct error if I understand this correctly.

Comment: Yes you do.____